# Slope interpretation in simple linear regression

Tags: regression

In simple linear regression, the interpretation of the slope parameter of a given linear model that is always taught is as follows:

"For every one unit increase in the explanatory variable (predictor), the response changes (increases/decreases) by a factor of $\beta_1$ units, all other parameters (intercept) held fixed."

In my work, I have several asymptotic curves where the response tends towards an upper limit. I am employing inverse regression in order to find the value of $x$ corresponding to some observed $y$. $y$ in my case corresponds to an horizontal asymptote. If the curve really is flat past some threshold of the predictor, then increasing the predictor will not have any effect on the response.

The reason for doing all of this is to say something about sampling completeness for biodiversity studies. For instance: Is it likely that all species known to occur in a given area have been observed? One way this can be tested is through examine rarefaction curves to see if they tend to some limit.

I am performing a linear regression on the last 10 points occurring on each my curves in order to test whether or not $\beta_1$ = 0 vs the alternative that $\beta_1$ > 0 (since the curve is monotonically increasing everywhere). The use of 10 points is rather arbitrary.

In doing this, I say something like:

"For every one unit increase in the response, the predictor changes by $\frac{1}{\beta_1}$"

My argument is as follows:

It is apparent that as curves get closer and closer to an asymptote ($y$), $\beta_1$ approaches 0. It stands to reason then that $\frac{1}{\beta_1}$ serves as the "limiting" value of $x$ corresponding to $y$.

Is the above statement a valid one to make?

I know that only using some of the available data is not good in practice without reason. The use of 10 points has been employed in the literature, but I know there must be better methods. One method I have proposed is to use a fixed fraction of points to carry out the regression (e.g., last 90% of datapoints). This has the effect of being dependent on the amount of data available for different species.

My curves don't fit any parametric model (e.g. power law, $y = ax^b$ very well), so I am appealing to semiparametric methods since curves are vastly different between the species I am working with. But, the overall trend that generated curves will eventually level off to a plateau is still the same

Comment: You seem to be asking us whether $\beta_1$--the value in your first quotation--and $1/\beta_1$--the value in your second--are always equal.  Evidently not.  Of greater import is the *ad hoc* procedure you describe of limiting your data to the last 10 points.  Usually there are better ways--but if you would like suggestions, you will need to describe your data and explain your objectives better.

Comment: @whuber Yes, I would like some suggestions. I have added more detail to my question post. Hopefully it makes things clearer.

Comment: @whuber Were you able to give some thought as to best approaching this question in light of my added details?